# Should I include API Key in query to avoid rate limiting?

Tags: oracles

I'm writing an oraclize query that contacts an endpoint that has a limit of 50 requests per day. Does oraclize only have one server and as a result will it get rate limited and start returning errors?

For example, If each node on the network has to confirm this block by replaying the events of the transaction, will they not also have to call the oraclize server and exceed the rate limit, or does oraclize have a method to circumvent this?

If not how would I include the encrypted api key in the header of the oraclize request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit headers as needed using the following computation example provided by Oraclize: https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests/urlRequests.sol

Uses python requests library, allowing for extensive HTTP capabilities.